# To find positive solution $(x,y)$ in integer satisfying equation $101x+37y=3819$

Tags: number-theory

**Prove that $$101x+37y=3819\cdots (1)$$ has a positive solution in integer.**

*I tried solving this by applying division algorithm to $101$ & $37$

$$101=2(37)+27$$
Put this in eqn (1) will give 
$$27x + 37 (y\;+\;2x)=3819$$
Then taking $$x'=x, y'=y+2x$$ we have
$$27x'+37y'=3819$$
Again applying division algorithm to $27$ & $37$, and following same procedure I got $$27x"+10y"=3819$$ where $$x"=x'+y'$$ & $$y"=y'$$ and repeating same procedure Similarly I got the step $$x^{(5)}+3y^{(5)}=3819$$ where $$x^{(5)}=x^{(4)}, y^{(5)}=y^{(4)}+2x^{(4)}$$.

Now if I apply division algorithm to $1$ & $3$ then remainder will be zero*

> Now I don't know how to proceed from here. Kindly whoever knows about this method help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3819=37\times 103+8$

Consider $101x+37(y-103)=8$.

\begin{align*}
(37\times 2+27)x+37(y-103)&=8\\
37(2x+y-103)+27x&=8\\
(27+10)(2x+y-103)+27x&=8\\
27(3x+y-103)+10(2x+y-103)&=8\\
(10\times 2+7)(3x+y-103)+10(2x+y-103)&=8\\
10(8x+3y-309)+7(3x+y-103)&=8\\
(7+3)(8x+3y-309)+7(3x+y-103)&=8\\
7(11x+4y-412)+3(8x+3y-309)&=8\\
(3\times 2+1)(11x+4y-412)+3(8x+3y-309)&=8\\
3(30x+11y-1133)+(11x+4y-412)&=8
\end{align*}

Set $30x+11y-1133=2$ and $11x+4y-412=2$. We have $x=14$  and $y=65$.

The general solution is $x=14+37n$, $y=65-101n$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. $x$ and $y$ are both positive when $n=0$.

So, $x=14$  and $y=65$.

---

To reduce the number of steps, I will use negative "remainders" if its magnitude is smaller.

\begin{align*}
(37\times 3-10)x+37(y-103)&=8\\
37(3x+y-103)+10(-x)&=8\\
(10\times 4-3)(3x+y-103)+10(-x)&=8\\
10(11x+4y-412)+3(-3x-y+103)&=8\\
(3\times 3+1)(11x+4y-412)+3(-3x-y+103)&=8\\
3(30x+11y-1133)+(11x+4y-412)&=8
\end{align*}

---

With your work, you can take $x^{(5)}={3819}-37n$, $y^{(5)}=101n$. Then express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $n$ and find suitable value of $n$ to make both $x$ and $y$ positive.

---

The purpose of reducing $3819$ to $8$ is for easier observations.

Notice that $37\times 4=148$. So, $37(4)+10(-14)=8$. Compare with the equivalent form "$37(3x+y-103)+10(-x)=8$" of the equation, we see that $3x+y-103=4$ and $x=14$ give a solution.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you. What next should I do after this step?

Comment: I will edit my answer to give more details

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks